# Pandas row value in a new column to dict

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to get this result. the column funz_id and funz_desc in a new column to dict.

```
soc_id     funz_id  funz_desc                                           funz_dict
     1  6410000000  Direzione {'funz_id': '6410000000', 'funz_desc': 'Direzione }
     1  6410000200      DG-GM     {'funz_id': '6410000200', 'funz_desc': 'DG-GM }
```

i try:

```
df['funz_dict'] = {'funz_id': df['funz_id'], 'funz_desc': df['funz_desc']}
```

but i get error <class 'ValueError'> - Length of values (2) does not match length of index (89)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.to_dict(orient='records')`:

`df[['funz_id', 'funz_desc']].to_dict(orient='records')` returns a list of dictionaries, one dictionary for each record/row:

```
[{'funz_id': 6410000000, 'funz_desc': 'Direzione'},
 {'funz_id': 6410000200, 'funz_desc': 'DG-GM'}]
```

So you can add a new column using:

`df['funz_dict'] = df[['funz_id', 'funz_desc']].to_dict(orient='records')`